# How to apply locale routing only for specific page while using next-i18next translation

Tags: next.js, next-i18next

I have 4 pages in nextjs project as index, service, contact-us, disclaimer. So I want next-i18next translation system only in index and service not in contact-us and disclaimer page. I made this translation work but still i found locale routing as localhost/fr/contact-us and localhost/fr/disclaimer.

I want to have generate locale translation system only for index and service and ignore remaing pages as it is.i dont want to generate locale for this two pages localhost/fr/contact-us and localhost/fr/disclaimer.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup temporary redirect (or anything else that suits your need) in `middleware.ts` for the pages for which you do not want to have localization. Something like the following:

```
export const middleware = (request: NextRequest): NextResponse => {
  if (request.nextUrl.pathname !== '/') {
    // for non-index paths, omit the locale
    // and temp redirect to the default url for the pages
    return NextResponse.redirect(
      new URL(
        `${request.nextUrl.pathname}${request.nextUrl.search}`,
        request.nextUrl.origin
      )
    );
  }

  return NextResponse.next();
};
```